# Ionic page change

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and angular js some one can help . i spend two days to create link from one page to other but fail.

this is button which is on default tabs page like (dash).
this is my controller :

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

       $scope.create = function () {
       alert("new post");
      $scope.go('templates/newspost');
  };

})
```

And this is my route

```
  .state('newspost', {
    url: '/newspost',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/newspost.html'
  })
```

i dont know where i make mistake.

Comment: This is button   : <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" ng-click="create()"></button>                                                                                               And newpost.html is a file in template directory.

Comment: `$scope.go('/newpost')` - you should go to the `url` not the `template` that is specified in your `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
<button class="button button-icon ion-compose" ui-sref="newspost">New Posts</button>
```

Or you can also use anchor tag:

```
<a href="#/newspost">New Post</a>
```

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax error.

```
 .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.create = function () {
   alert("new post");
  $scope.go('templates/newspost');  };})
```

you should write $state.go('templates/newspost') instead of $scope.go('templates/newspost') and also you should add $state to .controller function like this

`.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$state)`

Comment: Try add this in your route part  controller:'DashCtrl'' like this

  .state('newspost', {
    url: '/newspost',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/newspost.html',
 controller:'DashCtrl''
  })